# Question about applying Alpha zero general to different games

Tags: deep-learning

I’m trying to use alpha zero general to apply on a different game (kind of like Chess), this is the original code for othello:
https://github.com/suragnair/alpha-zero-general

However, after a few iterations (about 300 self play), it still seems like doing nonsense moves. So I’m wondering whether my code is wrong. Here are some few questions I came up with:

1. should num_channels be modified?
   note: I’m actually confused about the parameter “number of channels”. In my opinion, it should be at most 3 for othello (there are only “black”, “white” and “none” type of pieces), however, num_channels is set to 128 in the original case.
2. Another question is about the “board”, which will be the input of the nnet. The original code uses a 2D array to present a Othello board, which uses 1 to represent a white piece, -1 for the black piece, 0 for none.
   However, there are 6, for instance, kind of pieces in chess. Normally it should be input as a 3D dimension, 2D for the board, another dimension for different kinds of pieces. (or channel, just like an RGB 128*128 picture should be a 3D input (3*128*128))
   I now use a 2D array only, where 1,2,3,... represents king, queen, bishop, etc. I’m not sure if this causes a problem.

   I’ve tried to figure it out from the written code but I couldn’t find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to have a channel for each type of piece, or another more compact representation of the board. The reason has got to do with the 'squashing' functions (non-linearities) and the fact that the network is learning a continuous map.  You put too much of a 'burden' on a single input neuron. You will need a channel for each type of piece for each player, if you have 8 types of piece and 2 players you will need 16 channels. Use 0-1 matracies for each channel.

Think about what will happen to the input values if they are integers when we run them though this function.
[image: sigmoid]

Comment: Thanks, that’s similar to what I’ve expected.

Comment: please accept the answer, if you feel it answers your question - thanks!